# Fatal error: Class 'Conexao' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 5

Tags: php

Estou tendo este problemna de conexão com o banco

PHP:

```
$i = new Conexao();

$f = $imv['imovel_id'];

$i->ExecSQL("select * from imoveis_fotos where foto_imovel = '$f' limit 1");

$foto = $i->ListarDados();
```

PHP Conexão:

```
class Conexao {

private $host;
private $user;
private $senha;
private $bd;
private $link;
public  $query;
public  $lista;

//private $tabela;

/**
 *funcao construtora que inicia o link caso esteja null
 */
function __construct() {
    if ($this->link == NULL):

        $this->getConexao();    

    endif;


}

/*
 *faz a conexao caso não tenha valores no LINK
 */
public function getConexao() {
    $this->host = 'localhost';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->senha = '';
    $this->bd = 'imoveis';


    $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->senha) or die('Erro de conexão');
    mysql_select_db($this->bd, $this->link);
    mysql_set_charset('UTF8', $this->link); 
}
```

PHP Config:

```
<?php


function __autoload($class) {

$arquivo = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/app/{$class}.class.php";

if (file_exists($arquivo)):
    //require_once (Config.php);
    require_once ($arquivo);
else:
    die("<h1>Erro algum arquivo esta faltando</h1>");

endif;
```

Comment: Qual a versão php?

Comment: Versão 5.6.8 do PHP

Comment: Evite utilizar `mysql` pois está obsoleto, utilize `mysqli` ou `PDO`, aparentemente está tentado incluir a classe `Conexao` que está em `C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php`. Qual o diretorio que está o arquivo `Conexao`? Em `app` msm?

Comment: Sim, esta em Conexao

Comment: Acho que você não me entendeu... O arquivo `Conexao` está em qual pasta (diretório), esse erro está dando porque o `include` ou `require` está errado, precisa apontar para o local correto do arquivo.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Conexao.class.php

Comment: Então o problema está no `__autoload`, que não está funcionando corretamente. Faz `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` e veja o q ele mostra, normalmente `DOCUMENT_ROOT` traz até a raiz do projeto que no seu caso é `app`. Ou seja, `C:\xampp\htdocs\app`, então como vc escreveu `/app/{$class}.class.php`, o link para o arquivo ficou  `C:/xampp/htdocs/app/app/{$class}.class.php`

Comment: Muito obrigada.

Comment: Funcionou? Se sim, vou transformar o comentário em resposta e vc deixa com o simbolo de melhor resposta (verde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então o problema está no `__autoload`, que não está funcionando corretamente. Faz echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` e veja o q ele mostra, normalmente `DOCUMENT_ROOT` traz até a raiz do projeto que no seu caso é `app`. Ou seja, `C:\xampp\htdocs\app`, então como vc escreveu `/app/{$class}.class.php`, o link para o arquivo ficou `C:/xampp/htdocs/app/app/{$class}.class.php`